# pip install requirements.txt issue when deploying Django app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, pip

I am trying to deploy my django app on Heroku using the following guidance: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python. I reached the point where I have to create and populate the "requirements.txt" file with the following command:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However, I get the following error message

```
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

I tried two other commands

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt requirements.txt
$ pip install --allow-all-external requirements.txt
```

but in both cases I get the following error

```
Collecting requirements.txt
/home/bastien/python/framework/scrapping/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
SNIMissingWarning
/home/bastien/python/framework/scrapping/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Could you please tell me where the issue is coming from, how I can resolve it using the appropriate command lines or if there is a way to populate the requirements.txt file in any other way? Thanks.

Comment: this simply means that your requirements file is empty. You must put the list of requirements in there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pip install -r requirements.txt` does not populate `requirements.txt` - it reads it as the source of names of packages to install. See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files for further details.

To capture your current installed package list to a `requirements.txt`, try `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.